# Swift: Make an error handler of AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer for my app, and when the view controller loads the audio plays automatically as the view loads but how do I make a statement if the audio cannot find that file and when it can't find the file I want an alert message to pop up saying the audio cannot be found.

Code:

```
var euphoriaAudio = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: 
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Euphoria", ofType: "mp3")!))
```

Note: This variable declaration is not in any function. It is outside sitting alone in the class which works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Should do everything you described.

```
class EuphoriaViewController: UIViewController {
  var player: AVAudioPlayer?

  private func showAlert(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning",
      message: message,
      preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action in
      // Execute some code upon OK tap here if you'd like
    }

    alert.addAction(ok)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Euphoria",withExtension: "mp3") else {
      showAlert("Can't find Euphoria.mp3 resource")
      return
    }
    do {
      player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
      player?.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch {
      showAlert("Can't load Euphoria.mp3 resource")
    }
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    player?.play()
  }
}
```

Next time, try it yourself and post questions like - I did this, but it doesn't work, here's the code, ...

If you don't know how to display alert, ... You should start with [Start developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/), [About iOS App Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1), ...

Also you should read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get your questions answered in the future. So far you have 10 questions, some of them answered, 3 of them with accepted answer, ... Try to ask better ...

Comment: Great suggestions, @robertvojta !!!  It is nice of you to take the time to give advice like this ;-)